# Spring security - why does RoleVoter supports all classes and WebExpressionVoter only supports subclasses of FilterInvocation?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-3

In the `supports(Class clazz)` method of `RoleVoter`, it always returns true saying that

> This implementation supports any type of class, because it does not
>   query the presented secure object.

What is this "**presented secure object**". On the other hand, the `supports(Class clazz)` method of `WebExpressionVoter` returns true only if `clazz` is a subtype of `FilterInvocation`. Is `FilterInvocation` the "presented secure object" here and why does the voter has to support it ?

If I use `@Secured` annotations over my methods and configure an access decision manager for global method security  that has `WebExpressionVoter` as one of the voters, it presents an error

> AccessDecisionManager does not support secure object class: interface
>   org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation

This is because all voters of an access decision manager (when configured for method security) must support the above class, and while `RoleVoter` and others do, `WebExpressionVoter` needs a subtype of `FilterInvocation`.

`SPEL` expressions in `@PreAuthorize` tag would also need `WebExpressionVoter`, and again it would be required to support `MethodInvocation` class, which it doesn't. But it does work. So what am I getting wrong here ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `secured object` is an abstract representing whatever is secured. It may be a `MethodInvocation` in case of `@Secured`, `@RolesAllowed`, `@PreFilter` and `@PreAuthorize`, or a `FilterInvocation` in case of `<intercept-url />` or any other object if required.

The `@PreFilter` and `@PreAuthorize` annotations are handled by `PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter`. It uses the `MethodInvocation` to get the annotations and their attributes values, so it has:

```
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return clazz.isAssignableFrom(MethodInvocation.class);
}
```

The `WebExpressionVoter` is web-invocation specific, because it matches the URL to the patterns from `<intercept-url />`, that's why it has:

```
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return clazz.isAssignableFrom(FilterInvocation.class);
}
```

The `RoleVoter` only uses the `Authentication` object contents, so it does not depend on the `secured object`, and that's why it has:

```
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return true;
}
```

Note, that You can have a separate `AccessDecisionManager` for URL level security and method level security. The first will use voters that support `FilterInvocation`, and the other the ones that support `MethodInvocation`. Also note that `RoleVoter` supports both so it can be used in both contexts.